# The word scans can be used with (has or have)

Tags: grammar

Please which sentence is more accurate grammatically:

```
Here is a list with all the scans that has been done till today
Here is a list with all the scans that have been done till today
```

I Googled "has been done" and "have been done" and the results came close. Which one is more accurate?

Comment: You are not refering to the list but to the scans, and this word is plural so **have**.

Comment: I@m not exactly sure though, whether "till" is correct here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *"have/has"* refers to is **"scans"**. This word is plural (singular=scan). With the plural countable noun it is correct to say **"have"**.